# Dart window custom object

Tags: dart

What is the equivalent in Dart of the javascript statement:

```js
window.myObject = cookie[1]
```

Where myObject is being used as a global state holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to create global variables in Dart.

You could create a library like

```dart
library my_globals;

var aGlobalValue;
```

You have access to this variable wherever you import `my_globals`.

The advantage is, that this prevents conflicts with global variables of any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling of this but needed to check to see if I missed a more direct translation.

Comment: This doesn't work if you compile it to javascript. You will get different instances. dart 1.0

Comment: @yichen Do you have a reference (Dart issue, discussion, ...)